# Does wordpress have an error log?

Tags: errors, fatal-error

I accidentally removed a bunch of plugin folders. I restored them all directly after, but since then my site is completely blank. Can't see anything, it's just white.

I'm not sure what to do, but looking at a log file seems like a good start. Is there one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not one if you didn't set one up.  The [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Editing_wp-config.php#Configure_Error_Log) has a good example of how to do this.

```
<?php
@ini_set('log_errors','On');
@ini_set('display_errors','Off');
@ini_set('error_log','/home/example.com/logs/php_error.log');

/**
 * This will log all errors notices and warnings to a file called debug.log in
 * wp-content (if Apache does not have write permission, you may need to create
 * the file first and set the appropriate permissions (i.e. use 666) ) 
 */
define('WP_DEBUG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_LOG', true);
define('WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY', false);
@ini_set('display_errors',0);
```

White screen of death is usually caused by WordPress looking for the active theme and not finding it.  If you can access the admin area, got to Appearance > Themes and reactivate your theme.

Comment: I'm guessing that will only log PHP errors though? I was hoping for a wordpress-internal error log kind of, so it logs wordpress errors when something breaks (like it did now). Like `Theme was not found, causing white screen of death` or something like that. I fixed it btw, i guess i uploaded the theme in the wrong dir or something because i re-opened filezilla and found that the theme folder wasn't there. (I still don't know where the other copy is)

Comment: Nope, no internal error log like that, unfortunately.

Comment: White screen of death will be caused by PHP errors, and the way PHP and Wordpress work means that once PHP encounters a major error it'll stop entirely - which means that any Wordpress error-logging function might not get run at all!

Comment: @guiniveretoo If it was caused by a PHP error i should be able to see the error, shouldn't i? Also, i'm not sure, but i would imagine wordpress is smart enough to check if a theme exist before it tries to load it, and if it's not found, display a white screen of death (which, if my theory is correct, should be replaced with an error message).

Comment: Most servers (correctly) turn off printing errors to the screen. If you can see errors on your live site, it's a security vulnerability. If you are getting the white screen of death on your live site, most decent hosting companies will have a log file somewhere in your file structure that will log the most recent PHP errors - if you can't find one, I'd contact them to find out how to turn it on.

Comment: You could also log a bug report/feature request on the Wordpress trac if this is functionality you want. :)

Answer (score 2):

Something I find super helpful is a plugin called *Debug Bar*. Really helpful for showing what actions are being run, also shows notices and warnings, etc. Super helpful to have in a dev environment. I'm not the developer of the plugin btw.

> #### [Debug Bar](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/debug-bar/)
>
> *Adds a debug menu to the admin bar that shows query, cache, and other helpful debugging information.*